# Texture Bleeding despite disable mipmaping and half pixel correction

Tags: javascript, webgl, pixi.js

I've applied two necessary steps given in this answer https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/46963/how-to-avoid-texture-bleeding-in-a-texture-atlas, but I still get texture bleeding.

I have an atlas that has filled with solid colors at bounds: `x y w h: 0 0 32 32, 0 32 32 32, 0 64 32 32, 0 32 * 3 32 32`

I want to display each of these frames using webgl without texture bleeding, only solid colors as is.

I've disabled mipmaping:

```
gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_S, gl.REPEAT);
gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_T, gl.REPEAT);

//gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, gl.LINEAR_MIPMAP_LINEAR);
gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, gl.LINEAR);
gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, gl.LINEAR);
```

I've applied half pixel correction:

```
  const uvs = (src, frame) => {
    const tw = src.width,
          th = src.height;

    const getTexelCoords = (x, y) => {
      return [(x + 0.5) / tw, (y + 0.5) / th];
    };

    let frameLeft = frame[0],
        frameRight = frame[0] + frame[2],
        frameTop = frame[1],
        frameBottom = frame[1] + frame[3];

    let p0 = getTexelCoords(frameLeft, frameTop),
        p1 = getTexelCoords(frameRight, frameTop),
        p2 = getTexelCoords(frameRight, frameBottom),
        p3 = getTexelCoords(frameLeft, frameBottom);

    return [
      p0[0], p0[1],
      p1[0], p1[1],
      p3[0], p3[1],
      p2[0], p2[1]
    ];
  };
```

But I still get texture bleeding. At first I tried using pixi.js and I got texture bleeding too, then I tried using vanilla js.

I've fixed this, by changing these lines:

```
    let frameLeft = frame[0],
        frameRight = frame[0] + frame[2] - 1,
        frameTop = frame[1],
        frameBottom = frame[1] + frame[3] - 1;
```

As you can see I subtract 1 from right and bottom edges. Previously these indexes are 32 which means beginning of the other frame, It has to be 31 instead. I don't know if this is the correct solution.

Comment: Only a guess. If you have a retina or HDPI display then the DOM can smooth the canvas during compositing if the canvas res does not match the pixel size.Try adding CSS rule `image-rendering: pixelated;` to the canvas element.

Comment: @Blindman67, smoothing the canvas has nothing to do with hd-dpi. It has to do with the canvas's drawingBuffer being a different size than it is displayed. This can happen anywhere, even on a non HDPI display. [example](https://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/webgl-10x15-canvas-400x300-css.html). Also image-rendering: pixelated with webgl is Chrome only ATM. Also texture bleeding is a different issue. See the link at the top of the question.

Comment: @gman. Well gee duh.

Comment: @Blindman67 If you knew it was wrong and/or you knew it was irrelevant then why the comment?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your solution is correct.

Imagine we have a 4x2 texture with two 2x2 pixel sprites

```
+-------+-------+-------+-------+
|       |       |       |       |
|   E   |   F   |   G   |   H   |
|       |       |       |       |
+-------+-------+-------+-------+
|       |       |       |       |
|   A   |   B   |   C   |   D   |
|       |       |       |       |
+-------+-------+-------+-------+
```

The letters represent the centers of the pixels in the textures.

```
(pixelCoord + 0.5) / textureDimensions
```

Take the 2x2 sprite at A, B, E, F. If your texture coordinates go anywhere between B and C then you'll get some of C mixed in if you have texture filtering on.

Originally you were computing coords A, A + width where width = 2. That lead you all the way from A to C.  By adding the -1 you get just A to B.

Unfortunately you have a new issue which is that you're only displaying half of A and B. You can solve that by padding the sprites. For example make it 6x2 with the pixel bewteen being the edges of the sprite repeated

```
+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
|       |       |       |       |       |       |
|   E   |   F   |   Fr  |   Gr  |   G   |   H   |
|       |       |       |       |       |       |
+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
|       |       |       |       |       |       |
|   A   |   B   |   Br  |   Cr  |   C   |   D   |
|       |       |       |       |       |       |
+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
```

Above Br is B repeated, Cr is C repeated. Setting repeat as `gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE` will repeat A and D for you.  Now you can use the edges.

Sprite CDGH's coords are

```
p0 = 4 / texWidth
p1 = 0 / texHeigth
p2 = (4 + spriteWidth) / texWidth
p3 = (0 + spriteHeigth) / texHeight
```

The best way to see the difference is to draw 2 sprites large using both techniques, the unpadded and the padded.

```js
const numSprites = 3;
const spriteSize = 16;
const m4 = twgl.m4;
const gl = document.querySelector('canvas').getContext('webgl');

const spriteElem = makeSprites();
log('sprites');
document.body.appendChild(spriteElem);
const paddedSpriteElem = padSprites(spriteElem);
log('padded sprites');
document.body.appendChild(paddedSpriteElem);

const unpaddedTex = twgl.createTexture(gl, {src: spriteElem, wrap: gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE, minMax: gl.LINEAR});
const paddedTex = twgl.createTexture(gl, {src: paddedSpriteElem, wrap: gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE, minMax: gl.LINEAR});

const vs = `
attribute vec4 position;
attribute vec2 texcoord;
varying vec2 v_texcoord;
uniform mat4 matrix;
void main() {
  gl_Position = matrix * position;
  v_texcoord = texcoord;
}
`;

const fs = `
precision highp float;
varying vec2 v_texcoord;
uniform sampler2D tex;
void main() {
  gl_FragColor = texture2D(tex, v_texcoord);
}
`;

const program = twgl.createProgram(gl, [vs, fs]);
gl.useProgram(program);

const ploc = gl.getAttribLocation(program, 'position');
const tloc = gl.getAttribLocation(program, 'texcoord');
const mloc = gl.getUniformLocation(program, 'matrix');
// no need to look up 'tex' as we're only using 1 texture and uniforms default
// to 0 so it will use texture unit 0, the default

const pbuf = gl.createBuffer();
gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, pbuf);
gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array([0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0]), gl.STATIC_DRAW);
gl.enableVertexAttribArray(ploc);
gl.vertexAttribPointer(ploc, 2, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);

const tbuf = gl.createBuffer();
gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, tbuf);
gl.enableVertexAttribArray(tloc);
gl.vertexAttribPointer(tloc, 2, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);

const ibuf = gl.createBuffer();
gl.bindBuffer(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, ibuf);
gl.bufferData(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, new Uint8Array([0, 1, 2, 2, 1, 3]), gl.STATIC_DRAW);

gl.clearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);
gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

// un paddded using rect from centers
{
   const spriteId = 1;
   const texWidth = spriteElem.width;
   const texHeight = spriteElem.height;
   const x = spriteId * spriteSize;
   const y = 0;
   const p0x = (x + 0.5) / texWidth;
   const p0y = (y + 0.5) / texHeight;
   const p1x = (x + spriteSize - 1 + 0.5) / texWidth;
   const p1y = (y + spriteSize - 1 + 0.5) / texHeight;
   gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array([
     p0x, p0y,
     p1x, p0y,
     p0x, p1y,
     p1x, p1y,
   ]), gl.STATIC_DRAW);
   gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, unpaddedTex);
   
   let m = m4.ortho(0, gl.canvas.width, 0, gl.canvas.height, -1, 1);
   m = m4.translate(m, [2, 5, 0]);
   m = m4.scale(m, [96, 96, 1]);
   gl.uniformMatrix4fv(mloc, false, m);
   gl.drawElements(gl.TRIANGLES, 6, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, 0);
}

// paddded using rect from edges
{
   const spriteId = 1;
   const texWidth = paddedSpriteElem.width;
   const texHeight = paddedSpriteElem.height;
   const x = spriteId * (spriteSize + 2);
   const y = 0;
   const p0x = (x) / texWidth;
   const p0y = (y) / texHeight;
   const p1x = (x + spriteSize) / texWidth;
   const p1y = (y + spriteSize) / texHeight;
   gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array([
     p0x, p0y,
     p1x, p0y,
     p0x, p1y,
     p1x, p1y,
   ]), gl.STATIC_DRAW);
   gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, paddedTex);
   
   let m = m4.ortho(0, gl.canvas.width, 0, gl.canvas.height, -1, 1);
   m = m4.translate(m, [102, 5, 0]);
   m = m4.scale(m, [96, 96, 1]);
   gl.uniformMatrix4fv(mloc, false, m);
   gl.drawElements(gl.TRIANGLES, 6, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, 0);
}

// unpaddded using rect from edges (bleeding)
{
   const spriteId = 1;
   const texWidth = spriteElem.width;
   const texHeight = spriteElem.height;
   const x = spriteId * spriteSize;
   const y = 0;
   const p0x = (x) / texWidth;
   const p0y = (y) / texHeight;
   const p1x = (x + spriteSize) / texWidth;
   const p1y = (y + spriteSize) / texHeight;
   gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array([
     p0x, p0y,
     p1x, p0y,
     p0x, p1y,
     p1x, p1y,
   ]), gl.STATIC_DRAW);
   gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, unpaddedTex);
   
   let m = m4.ortho(0, gl.canvas.width, 0, gl.canvas.height, -1, 1);
   m = m4.translate(m, [202, 5, 0]);
   m = m4.scale(m, [96, 96, 1]);
   gl.uniformMatrix4fv(mloc, false, m);
   gl.drawElements(gl.TRIANGLES, 6, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, 0);
}

function padSprites(elem) {
  const canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
  canvas.className = 'zoom';
  canvas.width = numSprites * spriteSize + (2 * numSprites - 1);
  canvas.height = spriteSize;
  const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
  let dstX = 0;
  const offsets = [
    // corners
    [-1, -1],
    [ 1, -1],
    [-1,  1],
    [ 1,  1],
    // edges
    [-1,  0],
    [ 1,  0],
    [ 0, -1],
    [ 0,  1],
    // middle
    [ 0,  0],
  ];
  for (let i = 0; i < numSprites; ++i) {
    const srcX = i * spriteSize;
    for (const offset of offsets) {
      ctx.drawImage(
        elem,
        srcX, 0, spriteSize, spriteSize,
        dstX + offset[0], offset[1], spriteSize, spriteSize,
      );    
    }
    dstX += spriteSize + 2;
  }
  return canvas;
}

function makeSprites() {
  const canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
  canvas.width = numSprites * spriteSize;
  canvas.height = spriteSize;
  canvas.className = 'zoom';
  const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
  ctx.font = '12px sans-serif';
  ctx.textAlign = 'center';
  ctx.textBaseline = 'middle';
  for (let i = 0; i < numSprites; ++i) {
    const x = spriteSize * i;
    const h = i / numSprites;
    ctx.fillStyle = hsl(h, 1, 0.4);
    ctx.fillRect(x, 0, spriteSize, spriteSize);
    ctx.fillStyle = hsl(h, 1, 0.85);
    for (let j = 0; j < spriteSize; j += 4) {
      ctx.fillRect(x + j, 0, 2, 2);
      ctx.fillRect(x, j, 2, 2);
      ctx.fillRect(x + j, spriteSize - 2, 2, 2);
      ctx.fillRect(x + spriteSize - 2, j, 2, 2);
    }
    ctx.fillStyle = hsl(h + 0.5, 1, 0.5);
    ctx.fillRect(x + 1, 1, spriteSize - 2, spriteSize - 2);
    ctx.fillStyle = hsl(h, 1, 0.5);
    ctx.fillText(String.fromCharCode(65 + i), x + spriteSize / 2, spriteSize / 2);
  }
  return canvas;
}

function hsl(h, s, l) {
  return `hsl(${h * 360},${s * 100}%,${l * 100}%)`;
}

function log(...args) {
  const elem = document.createElement('pre');
  elem.textContent = [...args].join(' ');
  document.body.appendChild(elem);
}
```

```css
canvas {
  display: block;
  image-rendering: pixelated;
  padding: 5px;
}
.zoom {
  zoom: 4;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://twgljs.org/dist/4.x/twgl-full.min.js"></script>
<pre>left  : rect from centers using unpadded texture
middle: rect from edges using padded texture
right : rect from edges using unpadded texture (bleeding)
 (note the red at the bottom left edge)</pre>
<canvas></canvas>
```